# How can I log into a site with java

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, selenium, authentication

So I'm selling a jar file, in order to download it, you need to sign up to a website. Now, I want to check when they are running the file, if they have a valid login to that website. I tried using htmlunit, but I was unable to get it to work. It for some reason broke the passwordfield and no one was able to figure out the solution.

What else can I do? I tried setting up Selenium but it seems that it needs a bunch of extra stuff in order to work, and I don't want users to have to download that.

Target site = https://www.paragonclient.com/login?bnc=1&rsn=noOb&fromProt=&lng=

Comment: is there actually a question here?

Comment: "How can I log into a site with java"

Comment: That's a very broad question.  Could you show what you've tried? "unable to get it to work" is not very descriptive.  It's better to show what you have so far & narrow the question to something specific.  Please see [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Look into HTTP Request Logging. If you log the flow of the user you can monitor your server and see what actions the user is taking by tracing the session id with the user id. Sorry if this is not what you are looking for